# Why am I asked to revise this statement?

Tags: academic-writing

This statement is an introduction to the review of related literature chapter for my case study at school.

Maybe *presents* is a better word for *accounts*, but that's it? The style is OK for a formal work, and I have also seen this pattern in the introductory statements of other literature.

Picture of statement:

[image: Pic]

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately requests for re-wording are off topic here as they are asking What To Write more than How To Write it. Regardless, this type of question is best asked of your teacher/whoever made the suggestion. They will be best place to offer insight into what is required and why.

Comment: Adding to @Thomo's comment above, this might be more on topic if reworded to ask *how to get something across clearly*. Generally, questions that focus on *technique* are more likely to be well received than questions that focus on the minutiae of a specific example. It's fine to use your writing as an *example*, but the question should still be answerable without the example. Compare the point on questions seeking rephrasing help in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our [Help]. You can [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the statement is very generic. It could be used on just any review in any topic. Make it more specific. Or remove it given that it is essentially content-free

For instance,
This chapter is about {name of topic}. It accounts and evaluates {specific names of works, main ones if too many}. We find that case studies address/show {specific problems}.

Comment: Agreed. **Which** case study? The introduction should introduce the general problem, and then the particular case you intend to study. "Various reports [1],[2] suggest reports of domestic violence are correlated with economic stress. For this case study, we analyze the relationship of twelve socioeconomic factors in New Jersey along with reports of domestic violence, rape, and other violent crimes between 1995 and 2005." **Introduce** what you will be writing about and why. Don't give the results; just think of this as an orientation so the reader knows what you will be talking about.